# Using FFmpeg with Direct Show

Tags: c++, ffmpeg, directshow

I have a problem using DirectShow for HD video streams from IP cameras. Direct Show does not seem to support HD video. I was thinking of using FFmpeg to grab the RTSP stream from the camera and pipe it to direct show. I'm wondering if this will produce HD video ? If not do you have any suggestions ?

Thanks in Advance

Comment: DirectShow has no HD limitations, some codecs do. There is no built in support for RTSP in particular, and standard H.264 decoder is only up to Full HD resolution. Third party filters extend this without limits.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Short answer yes.

A longer answer would be that HD streams are no different for SD streams. They just contain much more data and would require bandwidth. In your case you would need to know what type of encoding is being used by the IP camera. In most cases, it should be H.264. 
For playing back HD streams using directshow, you would require two filters:

1. A network receiver filter to receive data off a socket
2. A codec filter to decode the stream

If you are using a IP cam like Axis, it would be using H.264 codec and the stream would be over RTP.

You can take a look at Mainconcept SDK for a demo version of filters to support HD over RTP/H.264

Comment: Also VisioForge Video Capture SDK .Net support it. Full SDK, not just a filters like MainConcept. So, if you are need filters MainConcept is better, if ready to use SDK - VisioForge.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the information, I'm gonna check out the SDK's